# Possible to use `attribute` with `store_accessor`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5, is it possible to use the new attributes API with a field exposed via `store_accessor` on a `jsonb` column?

For example, I have:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  store_accessor :metadata, :publication_date
  attribute :publication_date, :datetime
end
```

Then I'd like to call `i = Item.new(publication_date: '2012-10-24')`, and have `metadata` be a hash like: `{ 'publication_date' => #<DateTimeInstance> }`.

However, the `attribute` call doesn't seem to be doing any coercion.

Hopefully I am missing something--it seems like being able to use these two features in conjunction would be very useful when working with `jsonb` columns. (Speaking of which, why doesn't the attributes API expose a generic `array: true` option? That would also be very useful for this case.)

Answer (score 3):

> I see that there is a project jsonb_accessor, but it seems a little heavyweight. It also seems to be designed for Rails 4 (I haven't checked whether it supports Rails 5).

You might check out a rather new (as of this writing) gem built atop the Rails 5+ Attributes API: [AttrJson](https://github.com/jrochkind/attr_json). I've recently started using it; some rough edges still, but the author/maintainer seems keen to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

After digging in a little more, I see that the Attributes API (as it currently exists in ActiveRecord) is not really appropriate for handling `jsonb` data—there would be duplicate info in the `attributes` hash, etc.

I do think it would be nice if ActiveRecord provided typecasting/coercion for `jsonb` fields. I see that there is a project [jsonb_accessor](https://github.com/devmynd/jsonb_accessor), but it seems a little heavyweight. It also seems to be designed for Rails 4 (I haven't checked whether it supports Rails 5).

I guess something like this might be in the works for Rails since the `ActiveRecord::Type` values are actually defined in ActiveModel.

For now I am using the following. I've never really loved Hashie, but this is relatively lightweight and easy to use:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  class Metadata < Hashie::Dash

    include Hashie::Extensions::Dash::Coercion
    include Hashie::Extensions::Dash::IndifferentAccess

    property :publication_date, coerce: Time

    def self.dump(obj); obj.as_json; end
    def self.load(obj); new(obj); end

  end

  serialize :metadata, Metadata
  store_accessor :metadata, :publication_date
end
```